# once something has been .remove() - can it be bought back? Or can original source be refreshed? jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having a bit an issue, just wondering if this is possible?

Lets say I have this...

```
<div id="box">

     <div data-ground="1">ONE</div>
     <div data-ground="2">TWO</div>
     <div data-ground="3">THREE</div>
     <div data-ground="4">FOUR</div>

</div>
```

The I use this to remove all but one particular div...

```
$('#box div[data-group!=3]').remove();
```

Now is there anyway to bring back the orginal child elements of the `div#box` - after they have been removed?

I made a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/N8vUy/4/

Any suggestions would be great thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/N8vUy/2/ - here is with 3rd item persisted

Comment: @Joshc Your fiddle removes all divs... should be $('#box > div[data-group!=3]').remove();

Answer (score 4):

You can't restore removed nodes except of re-creating them from scratch and inserting back into parent node.

Depending to your purpose maybe it's an option to just hide node and show it when you'll need.

```
$('#box div[data-group!="3"]').hide(); // hide node
$('#box div[data-group!="3"]').show(); // show node
```

Comment: Actually the node may be detached, but putting it back may be very tricky

Comment: Thanks - its good to know removed elements can't be restored, may check out detach in the morning and see if that will work for me. But yeah for my purpose css won't work this time.

Answer (score 2):

The [`remove` method](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) will not only take the elements out of the DOM, it will also unbind events and remove jQuery data for the elements, so even if you keep a reference to the elements, it doesn't just work to reinsert them in the DOM.

Use the [`detach` method](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead when you want to keep the elements:

```
var el = $('div[data-group!=3]');
el.detach();

$('#box').append(el);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/N8vUy/10/

Comment: Ok cool thanks Guffa will check .detach out and see if I can get it to work for my issue. I will check back to this tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 0):

$('a#button').on('click', function (){

```
$('div [data-group!="3"]').remove();
```

});

place 1 space after the div tag thats why all div tag have disappear after you click 
the link.

and for your first question 
you cant bring it back.

try to use .hide() and .show() 
or try toy use .toggle()

Comment: no the first example that he gave in http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/N8vUy/4/ <br/> is not working but now it is working,<br/> the first example has no parent tag. but if you remove the #box on his code it will clear all the div tags